# What would prevent IIS 7 from handling a URL including %20

Tags: iis, encoding

I am dealing with a web server that resets the connection on any URL that includes an encoded space. 
e.g. http//somehost/some%20path causes the connection to be reset. I don't think it is permissions related since if I rename the directory to somepath it resolves correctly. No error is returned, no error shows up in the logs.

Comment: I won't add this as an answer because servers aren't my thing. But my server is set up intentionally not to take anything with a % in the URL, to help prevent injection attacks. In older versions of IIS, I used URL scan, plus code in a vbscript include file that did a secondary check. In newer versions of IIS, I think I'm using URL rewriting, plus, again, the some code in a vbscript include file. What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: The server in question is IIS 7. It didn't have Rewrite installed, I did install in the process of synching it to another IIS 7 environment that is operating properly. Since it's not returning any HTTP Error, I'm starting to think it may be some router voodoo, and in this case I lack access to the router.

Comment: If it's Win 2008, anything in the failed request logs?